# there is no ado.net entity data model in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ado.net-entity-data-model

After installed Visual Studio 2013 and create a new MVC4 internet application project :
Visual Studio Doesn't have Ado.net Entity Data Model when i click on add->new item->
Why?
I reinstall it but ther is no change ...

Comment: I had similar problem working on other machine but not on mine. copied the zip file suggested by @damir but no luck.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046081/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-on-visual-studio-2013 There are two answers there. The MSI fixed it for me, use search at the suggested location.

Answer (score 23):

Here's an updated solution I found as I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015: [ado.net model for db is gone Visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553674/ado-net-model-for-db-is-gone-visual-studio-2015)

Paraphrasing: Change your installation of Visual Studio 2015 and include the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (via Control Panel > Program & Features > VS2015 > Change > Modify > Windows and Web Development > Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools).

After downloading the extension and restarting Visual Studio, you should be able to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model as a new item.

As I learned the hard way trying to follow older Visual Studio tutorials, trying to use View > Other Windows > Data Sources etc. doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: For VS2017: VS Installer->.Net Desktop Development->Tick Entity Framework 6 Tools

Comment: above comment works for me, thanks

Comment: One gotcha I ran into: I created a class library and didn't realize I'd picked .NET Standard (instead of .NET Framework...NOT .NET Core...good grief could this get more convoluted). Anyway. the ADO.NET Entity Data Model only appears for .NET Framework projects.

Answer (score 6):

You have to install a the Entity Framework NuGet Package by right-clicking the specific project and then select "Manage NuGet Package". It'll pop-up a Window where you can search for existing packages online and install them

Answer (score -3):

you should try to run VS as administrator. I've tried both ways, first, the common way that is to run VS with left click, doing it like this I have the same problem: no ADO.NET Entity Data Model option. However, if I run it as administrator (right click -> run as administrator) everything shows up.