# Missing "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have created new web project but I can't find ADO.net Entity DAta Model to add it.

[image]

How to fix it or Install it ?

Comment: Readers: Also see this SO question [Can't find ADO.net Entity Data Model template in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299332)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" and search for "EFTools.msi".

You should find two files, just install the most recent one (it should be about 960KB). This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 20):

i have the same problem, but there is no  "EFTools.msi" in  "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" for me...

UPDATE : 
i download and install **"Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013"** and it solved the problem \m/

[Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

Comment: Great, you forgot to view hidden files. That is why you are not able to wave down to EFTools.msi file. @MahdiRashid

Answer (score 7):

Some web tutorials show a 'ADO.NET data entity model' item in the 'Models->Add' menu. In **VS2015** this menu item is not shown. You need to **keep drilling down** by selecting 'New Item...' and then further selecting 'Data' from the pop-up dialog.

Comment: This is more relevant now, with VS 2015 than with the accepted answer. Should be higher up

Answer (score 4):

My solution was none like the above.
The .msi file was nowhere in the folders suggested in prior answers, nor doing a search in my hard drive found any EFTools.msi instances.

So the failsafe approach came through [this article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D_JF1za8hbkJ:www.programering.com/a/MDNzATNwATA.html+&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br&client=opera) (since the author appears to have completely removed the page from the server, I've changed the URL to a version of the page stored in Google's cache), which was poorly written by a chinese fella, so I'm gonna try to rewrite the steps in a clearer way:

The solution is as follows:

1. Open your VS2013 installation ISO (or pop the DVD in) and navigate to "\packages\EFTools" folder;
2. There you will find 2 files (a .cab file and a .msi file);
3. Copy both files to a directory on your hard drive;
4. [Optional]: You can create in that same directory, an empty .txt file ("Log.txt") so that the installation log output will be redirected to it later;
5. Open a MS-DOS command prompt (with administrative rights) and type the command: EFTools.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "Log.txt" [NOTE: If you did not perform step #4, then you do not need to type from the ' /log' on (inclusive)]
6. Wait patiently while the installation process finishes. Takes quite some time (guess never hurts to remind you that this needs to be done with VS2013 closed). The installation should go fine, anything weird will be logged into the text file (the one you created in step #4).

Or, you might just double-click the .msi file if you are feeling brave..

After installation, open VS2013 and try adding a new item to the Models folder. The "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" should have reappeared under the "Data" tab.

Recognition goes to the anonymous chinese poster on that link (er, "Melinda"?) - xiè-xiè!

Comment: My situation was identical to yours - no EFTools.msi to be found except on the installation media.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you are trying to do that in .Net Framework project. For example, when you are creating a project do not use a template called Windows Forms App (.Net Core), use Windows Forms **(.Net Framework)**. The (.Net Framework) extension is important.

Answer (score 2):

right click on your project--> properties---> framework target select 4.5 and should work.

Comment: This is completely different from all other answers, are you sure this answers the question?

Comment: yes when change the target franework of the project to higher version then the ado model will appear in the list

Answer (score 1):

It's only for Visual Studio 2012. For me this had no effect on 2013.

Comment: i'm using VS 2013, and it worked, try changing .Net framework :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if you have Visual Studio **2015 RC**, the "EFTools.msi" can't be downloaded from Microsoft

If you accidentally delete the "ProgramData" folder, the Repair option will not work, you have to use the Add or Remove features option from the installer, and check the **SQL Server Data Tools**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the type of project you've added is for .NET Framework and not for .NET Standard. The templates for adding things such as ADO.NET Entity Data Model are included for .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 the following works.

Create project:

- Create new project of type 'Class Library'
- Install 'Entity Framework' from NuGet

Now add datamodel:

- In project click 'Add New Item'
- Select 'Visual C# Items' -> 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model'

Answer (score 1):

I recently added Entity Framework and installed in one of my many projects in a single sln file.

The thing is Entity Framework works on Framework higher than 3.5.

So Class Library of NET Standard wouldn't support Entity Framework, thus missing `Ado.Net Entity Data Model`, Since NET Standard console Library is Framework 2.0, changing the class Library to .NET Framework one, will include `Ado.Net Entity Data Model`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but found out that I was selecting ASP.NET Core web App, ASP.NET Core web App(MVC) etc, Instead Choose **ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** and you will get the **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to visual studio installer.

Add:
Entity framework tool 6

Download and install it.