# Ado.net not available as new item in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I created a new Project in Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core 2.0. 
It turned out, that there is no *Ado.net entity data model* item in the new item dialog.

I've seen this link [Missing “Ado.Net Entity Data Model” on Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046081/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-on-visual-studio-2013)
. But there is no EFTools.msi in the suggested directory nor can i install *Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013* for Visual Studio 2017.

Regarding this link: [Can't find ADO.net Entity Data Model template in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031516/7302498)
 I checked as well under Programms&Features->Visual Studio 2017->Change->Components and there *Entity-Framework Tools 6* is selected an apparently installed.

I tried with starting Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator as well.

Every help is very appreciated.

[image: Configuration Visual Studio 2017]

Comment: EF6 is not supported in Net Core projects. And [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) supports Code First only, so there is no ADO.NET Entity Data Model (edmx).

Comment: @Ivan Stoev. Ok thanks for clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. If you start with existing database, you can try the [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) command.

Answer (score 0):

**ADO.NET Data Model** is available in **.Net Framework** but your project is **.Net Core** type. You can add a ClaasLibrary(.NetFramwork) project to your solution then add a  ADO.NET Data Model to it.