# ado.net model for db is gone Visual studio 2015

Tags: model, ado.net

After installing the community version of Visual Studio 2015, I've run into a problem with my database connector, the ADO.net model. I usually connect to that with EF 5 or 6 depending on whether I'm using MYSQL or SQL Server.

But I've run in to the problem that I simply don't see it anymore. This is what I see: [image: http://i.imgur.com/idJH106.png]

Compared to Visual Studio 2013: [image: http://i.imgur.com/g4KTMeM.png]

I've tried reinstalling EF6.

However I can't find out if this is intentional or not. Does anyone have any idea what I should do? I'll obviously stick to VS2013 as of now. But I wanna get working with 2015 asap.

Comment: is visual studio installed in c drive ?

Comment: Yes. Should that really have anything to say though?

Answer (score 33):

obviously the EF just isn't available for VS 2015 for now... I searched for hours now, but there seems to be no way to get this working. I'll use VS 2013 to update my data model from the database.

check the following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/03/10/ef6-1-3-rtm-available.aspx

**EDIT:**

I found a solution :)

Just change your installation of VS 2015 and include the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (via Control Panel>Program & Features>VS2015>Change>Customize(? I see the german word there)>Windows- and Webdevelopment>Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools).

This will bring you back the .edmx designer and the ADO.NET model.

Comment: "Customize" is "Change" in Windows 10.

Comment: Perfect solution. Works on VS 2015 Community either.

Comment: "Customize" was "Modify" for me (Windows 7)

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is made up of the EF Tools for Visual Studio and the EF Runtime.
Installing EF Tools (**Entity Framework Tools**) can help you find the missing templates .

In order to install newer version you could **go to** ->

```
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache
```

(paste the **location** to address tab of windows explorer)

you could find some folders in that location search for `EFTools.msi`,install the latest(if you find multiple) file .

**Second solution is :**

1. Open your Visual studio installation package and find for : `EFTools`
   in /packages.
2. Copy both `.cab` and `.msi` files of `eftools`
3. Also create a Log.txt file in a folder where you are going to paste above files (you could use `C:\Temp`)
4. Open `cmd` in **Admin** privilege and type : `EFTools.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "Log.txt"`

Comment: Thanks utility. I tried this. Still no ADO.net model can be added. I have the log file. But I can't seem to see anything, but i'm no expert at reading those though

Comment: i tried solution 2 and it didn't make a difference. ADO.NET templates are missing and entity model designer doesn't appear when opening an .edmx file in an existing project.

log file is here: http://codewithoutborders.com/posted/Log.txt

Comment: note that there's some confusion in my log file about the installation location. i had installed the 2015 RC in c:\vs13, then I uninstalled it and installed RTM in c:\vs14, but it seems that the installer is still trying to install things in the old location (c:\vs13). i'm not sure, but I imagine this could be the source of the problem.

Comment: I found the file, installer offered me to repair, but those tools are made for 2013 version, so wont touch 2015. At last that was my case (I have both 2013 and 2015)

Answer (score 3):

So I found out that if you add the wrong template, then some items won't be available. I added a project of "Class Library (.NET core)". This didn't give me access to the template "ADO.NET Entity Data Model". When I deleted that and added the generic "Class Library" template (which I didn't see the first time) I was able to access the Entity Data Model.

I was using the Visual Studio 2015 Community version.