# How can I call a SQL Stored Procedure using EntityFramework 7 and Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

For last couple of days I am searching for some tutorials about how to call a `Stored Procedure` from inside a `Web API` controller method using `EntityFramework 7`.

All tutorials I came through are showing it the other way round, i.e. `Code First` approach. But I already have a database in place and I need to use it to build a `Web API`. Various business logic are already written as Stored Procedures and Views and I have to consume those from my Web API.

Question 1: Is this at all possible to carry on with `Database First` approach with `EF7` and consume database objects like above?

I installed `EntityFramework 6.1.3` to my package by the following `NuGet` command:

`install-package EntityFramework`
which adds version 6.1.3 to my project but immediately starts showing me error message (please see the screenshot below). I have no clue about how to resolve this.

[image]

I have another test project where in `project.json` I can see two entries like following:

`"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",`

However, when I am searching in `Nu-Get` package manager, I don;t see this version! Only 6.1.3 is coming up.

My main objective is to consume already written Stored Procedures and Views from an existing database.

1) I do not want to use `ADO.Net`, rather I would like to use `ORM` using `EntityFramework`

2) If `EntityFramework 6.1.3` has the ability to call `Stored Procs` and `Views` from already existing database, how I can resolve the error (screenshot)?

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: How you use Entity Framework currently? Could you include small example how you use it currently? I personally use also STORED PROCEDURES, which I call mostly in Controller Action and rerurns the results from Web Api. It allows me don't define any classes (Entities) for tables at all. My JavaScript code depends on the names from columns returned from STORED PROCEDURES, but not my C# code. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162630/315935). Thus there are many implementation options. If you would post an example of your current code, then it would be better to show how to help you.

Comment: You probably can't see version 7 of Entity Framework in NuGet because you have the "stable only" checkbox checked. This excludes pre-release versions, and the "rc" in "EF7 rc1" stands for "release candidate" (i.e. pre-prelease).

Comment: @Oleg: I never used Stored Procedure with EntityFramework before. But here the database is already created so I have to use the same. My part is to develop the Web API for the ongoing mobile version development. It would really be a great help if you please give me a sample code.

Comment: @Gary - I tried with "Include prerelease" checkbox checked but still did not get "rc" version of EntityFramework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope that I correctly understand your problem. You have existing STORED PROCEDURE, for example `dbo.spGetSomeData`, in the database, which returns the list of some items with some fields and you need to provide the data from Web API method.

The implementation could be about the following. You can define an **empty** `DbContext` like:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
}
```

and to define `appsettings.json` with the connection string to the database

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

You should use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to add `MyDbContext` to the

```
public class Startup
{
    // property for holding configuration
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        // save the configuration in Configuration property
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
            });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can implement your WebApi action as the following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyDbContext _context { get; set; }

    public MyController([FromServices] MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
        var returnObject = new List<dynamic>();

        using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.spGetSomeData";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // set some parameters of the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@someParam",
                SqlDbType.TinyInt) { Value = 1 });

            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                cmd.Connection.Open();

            var retObject = new List<dynamic>();
            using (var dataReader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                    for (var iFiled = 0; iFiled < dataReader.FieldCount; iFiled++) {
                        // one can modify the next line to
                        //   if (dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled))
                        //       dataRow.Add(dataReader.GetName(iFiled), dataReader[iFiled]);
                        // if one want don't fill the property for NULL
                        // returned from the database
                        dataRow.Add(
                            dataReader.GetName(iFiled),
                            dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled) ? null : dataReader[iFiled] // use null instead of {}
                        );
                    }

                    retObject.Add((ExpandoObject)dataRow);
                }
            }
            return retObject;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code just execute using `exec dbo.spGetSomeData` and use dataRader to read all results and save there in `dynamic` object. If you would make `$.ajax` call from `api/My` you will get the data returned from `dbo.spGetSomeData`, which you can directly use in JavaScript code. The above code is very transparent. The names of the fields from the dataset returned by `dbo.spGetSomeData` will be the names of the properties in the JavaScript code. **You don't need to manage any entity classes in your C# code in any way. Your C# code have no names of fields returned from the stored procedure. Thus if you would extend/change the code of `dbo.spGetSomeData` (rename some fields, add new fields) you will need to adjust only your JavaScript code, but no C# code.**

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you very much for your quick and detailed reply. Now I have some light! I will try this and get back to you with my experience.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: You are welcome! You can see that the code of the Get action very common and one can share the code just using different name of the stored procedure (`dbo.spGetSomeData`) and the list of parameters. You can use `cmd.Parameters.AddRange` and provide array of `SqlParameter` filled for the specific stored procedure. I think that you understand what I mean. I just want to make the code of Get action mostly small and simple to show the main idea writing C# code, which calls stored procedure and returns *transparently* the results which can be used in JavaScript code.

Comment: Great! You have made my day :) I am now able to call a very simple store procedure which lists a set of records using `Inner Join`. I should now be able to carry on with more complex parts. In case of any doubt, guess what.. I will give you a bit of more trouble.

Comment: Question: How can I call a `View` directly instead? Or I should get back to the old days i.e. by creating a `Stored Procedure`, calling the `view` inside it and finally consume this SP from my controller?

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: SELECT statement, which you can use in `cmd.CommandText` is absolutely common. You can use `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM vwMyViewFromDatabase"`. You need just remove `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`. You can use `SELECT` with parameters and just set the value of the parameter exactly like in case of usage STORED PROCEDURE.

Comment: @ Opps! I have been a fool. :P

Comment: @Oleg what you have above is more about using ado.net to call sp.  we can use below statement to call the sp in EFCore way Set<sp_return_type>().FromSql("[sp_name]").AsNoTracking();

Comment: @user1447718: I'm not full understand what you mean. In my approach one can use any stored procedure with any parameter. The most goal is the usage of Entity Framework Core function **without** defining any entity in C# code. The *full SELECT results* with all fields, which returns the specified stored procedure, will be return as JSON data from HTTP Get. As the result one need to maintain only the code of STORED PROCEDURE and JavaScript file. The C# code returns `new List<dynamic>` and it's *transparent* to any changes of database model (adding new column, rename columns, ...).

Answer (score 5):

`DbContext` has a `Database` property, which holds a connection to the database that you can do whatever you want with:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Foo>("exec [dbo].[GetFoo] @Bar = {0}", bar);
```

However, rather than doing this in your Web Api actions, I would suggest either adding a method to your context or to whatever service/repository that interacts with your context. Then just call this method in your action. Ideally, you want to keep all your SQL-stuff in one place.

Comment: I would like to do it in more EF-ish way, by dropping an SP on a EDM designer tool, marking its type (Scalar, Complex etc.) and finally calling it just like an object of EntityFramework. And it would be great if I can do all these using `ASP.NET` and `EntityFramework 7`. If 7 is not the solution I can get back to previous versions like `6.1.3`, but this is giving me an error which I have no idea bout how to resolve. Also I don't see any `Entity Data Model` (EDM) template available to add to my project in VS 2015 Community edition!

Comment: That's *not* the "EF-ish" way. EF dropped support for EDMX in EF7. The EDM designer is deprecated, and good riddance.

Comment: Yes,  EF7 has dropped EDM. Do you have any idea whether this been taken out permanently or it's a temporary catch?

Answer (score 1):

Just as the above answer, you could simply use the FromSQL() instead of SqlQuery<>().

```
context.Set().FromSql("[dbo].[GetFoo] @Bar = {0}", 45);
```

Comment: I just get `The type arguments for DbContext.Set<TEntity>() cannot be inferred from the usage`

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you used, also, what .NET framework are you working with?

Comment: .net core 1.1.0.   No `context.Set().FromSql()` method

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL connector and Entity Framework core 2.0

My issue was that I was getting an exception like fx. Ex.Message = "The required column 'body' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.". 
So, in order to fetch rows via a stored procedure in this manner, you must return all columns for that entity type which the DBSet is associated with, even if you don't need all the data for this specific call.

```
var result = _context.DBSetName.FromSql($"call storedProcedureName()").ToList();
```

OR with parameters

```
var result = _context.DBSetName.FromSql($"call storedProcedureName({optionalParam1})").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Database first approach , you have to use Scaffold-DbContext  command

Install  Nuget packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

but that will not get your stored procedures. It is still in the works,tracking issue [#245](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245)

But, To execute the stored procedures, use [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) method which executes RAW SQL queries

e.g.

```
var products= context.Products
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProducts")
    .ToList();
```

To use with parameters

```
var productCategory= "Electronics";

var product = context.Products
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProductByCategory {0}", productCategory)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var productCategory= new SqlParameter("productCategory", "Electronics");

var product = context.Product
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetProductByName  @productCategory", productCategory)
    .ToList();
```

There are certain limitations to execute RAW SQL queries or stored procedures.You can’t use it for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. if you want to execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries, use the ExecuteSqlCommand

```
var categoryName = "Electronics";
dataContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.InsertCategory @p0", categoryName);
```