# SqlDataReader returns blank instead of null for an int field

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am using SqlDataReader to fetch data from a SQL Server 2012 database:

```
SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection();
await connection.OpenAsync();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.[sp_MyStoredPrc] @InputId=1", connection);
var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int? var1 = (int?)reader["Column1Name"];
    }
}
```

When reading a NULL `int` field from the database, 
`reader["Column1Name"]` is blank so the code throws an InvalidCastException at runtime.

I have tried

```
reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1Name"))
```

but this throws System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException.

I have also tried

```
reader.GetSqlInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1Name"))
```

which returns null, but the type is `SqlInt32` and not `int?` like I want.

I ended up doing

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1Name"))) 
    int? var1 = (int?)reader["Column1Name"];
```

which works.

Questions:

1. Isn't there a simpler way than calling the `IsDBNull` method?
2. Why does `reader["Column1Name"]` return blank instead of `null` if the db value is NULL and the field is an `int`?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to use Convert.ToInt32(reader["Column1Name"]);

Comment: I get an exception because Reader["Column1Name"] is blank

Comment: Are you sure that db value is null? It can be empty but it doesn't mean it is null. Otherwise there is no easy way to deal with it than to check for empty value.

Comment: I am sure it is null I can do a SQL profiler trace to see ti returns a null. Also  reader.GetSqlInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1Name")) returns null

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Also, Column1Name and ColumnName1 are different fields?

Comment: It's a good question! On the other side I personally use the approach described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34764698/315935). It shows how to read generic information returned from reader to `List<dynamic>`. In the same way one can save the results in `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. As the result one can read the data and one have no problem with reading `null` because you read data by ordinal number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `reader["Column1Name"]` return blank instead of null if the db value is null and the field is an `int`?

Actually, `reader["Column1Name"]` returns [DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) if the database value is NULL. (In the Visual Studio debugger, the value appears to be blank because [DBNull.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an empty string.) You cannot cast `DBNull.Value` directly to `int?` using the cast operator.

> Isn't there a simpler way then calling the `IsDBNull` method?

Yes, use the `as` operator instead of a cast:

```
int? var1 = reader["Column1Name"] as int?;
```

Because `DBNull.Value` isn't an `int`, the `as` operator returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

C# cannot cast a string to a int? using (int?). The safest way is to use the conditional operator to check for null, then manually set the value to null.

```
//Get the column index to prevent calling GetOrdinal twice
int COLUMNNAME1 = reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName1");

while (reader.Read())
{
    int? var1 = reader.IsDBNull(COLUMNNAME1) ? null : reader.GetInt32(COLUMNNAME1);
}
```

Similarly, if you have non null data types, you can check them for null and set them to their default values.

```
int STRINGCOLUMN = reader.GetOrdinal("StringColumn");
int INTCOLUMN = reader.GetOrdinal("IntColumn");
int DATECOLUMN = reader.GetOrdinal("DateColumn");
int BOOLCOLUMN = reader.GetOrdinal("BoolColumn");

while (reader.Read())
{
    string var1 = reader.IsDBNull(STRINGCOLUMN) ? "" : reader.GetString(STRINGCOLUMN);
    int var2 = reader.IsDBNull(INTCOLUMN) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(INTCOLUMN);
    DateTime var3 = reader.IsDBNull(DATECOLUMN) ? DateTime.MinValue : reader.GetDateTime(DATECOLUMN);
    bool var4 = reader.IsDBNull(BOOLCOLUMN) ? false : reader.GetBoolean(BOOLCOLUMN);
}
```