# The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've just starting learning MVC6 with EF7.  I have a stored proc that I'd like to return a portion of the fields that are in my model.  If I don't return every field in my model, I'm getting "The required column 'FirstName' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation".

Is there a way to get make some columns not required so I can return just a portion of the fields in my model?

model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Protected ID")]
    public string ProtectedID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My proc for testing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[aaa_TopXXUsersTest]
@NumToReturn int = 10
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select top(@NumToReturn) UserID, LastName, Username,Password, ProtectedID from Users where Deleted = 0

END
```

and last, my controller code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var user = _context.Set<LoginViewModel>().FromSql("dbo.aaa_TopXXUsersTest @NumToReturn = {0}", 20);

    return View(user);
}
```

If I include all the fields of my model in my stored proc the call work fine, but I can't seem to return just a subset.  Is there a way to make some of the fields not required?

Comment: Probably the way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34764698/315935) will be good for you. It allows to use EF7 without the requirement to define class like `LoginViewModel`. You will get the `dynamic` object (which you can cast to object) with all properties returned by you stored procedure.

Comment: I'd hoped that the easy way was workable on this, but your link provided what I needed.  Thanks Oleg

Answer (score 24):

Used `[NotMapped]` attribute with first name.

> The `NotMapped`attribute can be applied to properties of an entity class for which we do not want to create corresponding columns in the database.

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Protected ID")]
        public string ProtectedID { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to include using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; I found this answer very helpful, thanks Sanjay Katiyar!!!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

this means that the column 'FirstName' is not being returned in the result set.
Do a 'SELECT * FROM TABLE' to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

To addition current answers:

According to last version, `FromSql` changed. Instead of that we can use eather `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated`

As mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql): `FromSqlInterpolated` is similar to `FromSqlRaw` but allows you to use string interpolation syntax. Just like `FromSqlRaw`, `FromSqlInterpolated` can only be used on query roots.

We can achieve excluding property from mapping, using [OnModelCreating](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method) method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Ignore<Property>();  //property needed to be excluded
}
```

or: `[NotMapped]` [attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/notmapped-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

It requires a Id column to be returned from the SP.

```
select top(@NumToReturn) 0 AS 'Id', UserID, LastName, Username,Password, ProtectedID 
  from Users 
 where Deleted = 0
```

Or Change `UserID` to `Id` from select and model

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this   public string FirstName { get; set; }. Your stored procedure is not returning the value for Firstname field, but you are trying to accept it in your loginViewModel class in this string Firstname variable.