# Run sql queries in net5 - winform

Tags: c#, winforms

how can run sql queries in c# win-form and net5, i wana run sql query something like this :

```
SELECT CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE) AS DATE, SUM(FinancePayment) AS Payment, FinanceType FROM Finances GROUP BY CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE), FinanceType
```

but i have a problem, in this case and net5 i have two method `FromSqlInterpolated()`,`FromSqlRow()` when i use this methods, i have an `Exception` : `The required column 'ID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation`.

code:

```
var finance = await dbContext.Finances.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE) AS DATE, SUM(FinancePayment) AS Payment, FinanceType FROM Finances GROUP BY CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE), FinanceType").ToListAsync();
```

**what can i do?**

Answer (score 0):

use DbCommand to execute queries:

```
mydbcommand.ExecuteReader( "SELECT CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE) AS DATE, SUM(FinancePayment) AS Payment, FinanceType FROM Finances GROUP BY CAST(FinanceDate AS DATE), FinanceType" );
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereader

Answer (score 0):

Used **[NotMapped]** attribute with ID.

> The NotMappedattribute can be applied to properties of an entity class
> for which we do not want to create corresponding columns in the
> database.

see this link for more details :
[The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778318/the-required-column-was-not-present-in-the-results-of-a-fromsql-operation)

Don't forget to include using **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema**