# net core - convert reader to json

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, asp.net-core

I am working with `.net core 1.0.1`. I want to execute a stored procedure from a Sql Server Table. I can connect to the database correctly, now I have the following code:

```
var con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.CommandText = "procedures.sp_Users";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Command", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "Login" } );
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "admin" } );
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "admin" } );

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

So I want to convert this `reader` to a JSON string for returning it in a controller.

How can I achieve it?

I read I can not use `DataTable` and `DataSet` because they are not cross-platform.

Comment: You could use `DataReaderConverter` from [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835729/json-net-serialize-directly-from-oledbconnection).  That converter serializes directly from any `IDataReader`.

Comment: dbc, I started using mssql via .net core today ... and though you seem to be sharing something useful I have to say ... it's just not enough for someone brand new, and that's who would be asking this question.  ... elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following:

```
var con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.CommandText = "procedures.sp_Users";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Command", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "Login" } );
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "admin" } );
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "admin" } );

var retObject = new List<dynamic>();
con.Open();
using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        var dataRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
        for (var iFiled = 0; iFiled < dataReader.FieldCount; iFiled++)
            dataRow.Add(
                dataReader.GetName(iFiled),
                dataReader.IsDBNull(iFiled) ? null : dataReader[iFiled] // use null instead of {}
            );

        retObject.Add((ExpandoObject)dataRow);
    }
}
return retObject;
```

As suggested in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745822/how-can-i-call-a-sql-stored-procedure-using-entityframework-7-and-asp-net-5)