# How to add a datamodel with entity framework 6 & .net-core-webapi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I've added EFF6 with .Net 4.6 as a dependency, I can see the references so the nuget package has added fine, build and runs, now there is no option to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model in the Templates pane ? Click here to go online and find templates is doing nothing either.

VS2015 Update 3 is applied.

Ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's you're missing some kind of install. Make sure you installed Entity Framework Tools and SQL Server Data Tools (via Control Panel > Program & Features > VS2015 > Change > Modify > Windows and Web Development > Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools)

[there is no ado.net entity data model in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073975/there-is-no-ado-net-entity-data-model-in-visual-studio)

[Missing "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" on Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046081/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-on-visual-studio-2013)